# Set the number of leaves of dendrogram in R's pheatmap

Tags: r, pheatmap

How can I define the number of leaves in the row of the pheatmap.

`pheatmap(res_sig,color = heat_colors, cluster_rows = TRUE,show_rownames = FALSE,          clustering_method="ward.D2",scale = "row")`

Also, Once I define the number of leaves/clusters, will the ordering of the genes (row-wise) in the heatmap change.

I've tried the cuttree option, but this simply adds space between a set of genes. I want to reduce the number of dendogram leaves.

Tried reading `?pheatmap` doc and searching for argument that allows you to define the number of clusters. Similarily searched for similar arguments in other library like ComplexHeatmap.